# Creation variable session express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm looking to create a variable that I could use on all the pages of my project in javascript, so I try to use express, the fact is that I can't assimilate a value to this session variable, my code is below:

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
app.use(session(
{
    secret:'XASDASDA',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
 
 
}
));
var ssn ;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    ssn=req.session;
   /*
   * Here we have assign the 'session' to 'ssn'.
   * Now we can create any number of session variable we want.   
   * Here we do like this.
   */
   // YOUR CODE HERE TO GET COMPORT AND COMMAND
   ssn.comport;
  
    ssn.comport="LebronJames";
    
});
 

console.log(ssn.comport);
```

the result in the console is the following :

```js
Typeerror : cannot set property 'comport' of undefined.
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line does? - ssn.comport;

Comment: thanks for your comment, this line is supposed to create the session variable "comport".

Comment: You would check the value of `req.session.comport` inside a request handler where the session is valid, not outside the request handler.  It's completely unclear what problem you're actually trying to solve, but it appears that you don't quite understand what one would use a session object for.  It's for saving state from one page to the next (for the same browser).  You only access it inside a request handler.

Comment: what i am trying to do here is define a variable on a page that will be defined on the whole project

Answer (score 0):

`ssn.comport;` => comport is not defined in this line. This is causing the error

Either you have to initialise with the some value or null like `ssn.comport=''` or **skip this line** as creating comport variable is done in the next line.

`ssn.comport="LebronJames";` => comport is declared and initialised simultaneously

Comment: thanks for your answer, i deleted ssn.comport; and it is still the same result in the console

Comment: the error is Typeerror : cannot set property 'comport' of undefined.

Comment: Just trying to debug. Can you share the output of console.log(ssn) at the end

Comment: the result says:  undefined